# SSAS Tabular/PowerBi - it's possible to convert unit to a K format in a chart in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, tabular

I am creating measures in SSAS Tabular, i want to change my numbers to a k format.
For example if i have :

Measure1 := SUM(Turnover$) =100.000
I want to have in PowerBi : 100k

i have tried the format function in dax :
Measure1 := FORMAT(SUM(Turnover$);"#,.0k").

That works in PowerBI but only for the table/Matrix/Card, that won't work for a chart (can't put my measure in the values field ).

So i was wondering if it's possible to auto-format a number and to put in a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use the FORMAT function at all. Keep the measure numeric:
`Measure1 := SUM(Turnover$)` put it in the line/column visual and then in the formatting options of the visual go to the `Data label` section and change display units to Thousands